# Как правильно заменить AsyncTask с помощью RxJava2 и RxAndroid2

Tags: android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

У меня есть `AsyncTask`, который я хочу переделать в Rx

Вот так выглядит мой `AsyncTask`

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {
        ArrayList<CallServiceCode> undoneServiceCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, ServicePartFormQuestionsManager> undoneForms = new HashMap<>();
        boolean isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();

            if (iCloseCallListener != null)
            {
                iCloseCallListener.onPreValidation();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            undoneServiceCodes = getUndoneServiceCodes();
            undoneForms = getUndoneForms();
            isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode = isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void iVoid)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(iVoid);

            if (iCloseCallListener != null)
            {
                iCloseCallListener.onPostValidation(undoneServiceCodes, undoneForms, isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode);
            }
        }
    }.execute();
```

Мне не понятно как можно выполнить в бекграунде Rx , можно выполнить сразу 3 разных метода как в примере с `AsyncTask` когда в бекграунде выполняется 3 метода

1. undoneServiceCodes = getUndoneServiceCodes();
2. undoneForms = getUndoneForms();
3. isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode = isHasAtLeastOneDoneServiceCode();

Если это был бы один метод(допустим первый) я бы это сделал так

```
Flowable.fromIterable(getUndoneServiceCodes())//
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//
            .doOnSubscribe(iSubscription ->
            {
                if (iCloseCallListener != null)
                {
                    iCloseCallListener.onPreValidation();
                }
            }).toList()//
            .subscribe(resultList -> {
                if (iCloseCallListener != null)
                {
                    iCloseCallListener.onPostValidation(iCloseCallListener, ???, ???);
                }
            });
```

Но так я получу результат только для одного выполняемого в бекграунде метода, как сделать так, чтоб можно было обрабоать 3?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться оператором `zip` как-то так (точность названий методов не гарантирую):

```
Flowable.zip(
    Flowable.fromCallable(method1()), 
    Flowable.fromCallable(method2()),
    Flowable.fromCallable(method3()),
    (result1, result2, result3) -> new Triple(result1, result2, result3) 
)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(triple -> iCloseCallListener.onPostValidation(triple.first, triple.second, triple.third))
```

Comment: Да действительно то что нужно, спасибо. Вот только не совсем удобно получается, что вот этот класс `Triple` - который по сути pojo обьект, так вот получается, что этот обьект занимает кучу строк... Конечно если использовать kolin то вообще проблем нет)

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, да, с котлином проще - там этот класс в стандартную либу входит) Если на Java - то можно просто в массив данные положить - тогда не надо будет лишние классы создавать. Хотя это, конечно, не очень красиво будет)